# Materialize CSS textbox expand Border from center animation

Tags: css-animations, materialize

[image]

I want to create this type of animation in textbox in materialize css. Checked many codepen an websites but can't find anything which helps with materialize css. Sometime two border display or sometime no effect.

Anyone provide some sourcecode of css so i can implement it. I don't want to include other css library. Only with materialize css and little bit css.

```
.input-field input[type=text]:focus {
     border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
     box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #000;
   }
```

I think customizing this after or before presudo will work.

Created Pen Here :

https://codepen.io/naitik_kundalia/pen/bRNeaz

I had created sliding border but it also work in reverse. Textbox removed on focus after animation end.

Answer (score 0):

Check this Pen:

```
$(".mat-input").focus(function(){
$(this).parent().addClass("is-active is-completed");
});
$(".mat-input").focusout(function(){
if($(this).val() === "")
$(this).parent().removeClass("is-completed");
$(this).parent().removeClass("is-active");
});
```

https://codepen.io/legeoffrey/pen/VYMLNq

Hope this will help you

Comment: I think it is possible with CSS only.